# MVC Client Cache is not working for Static content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clientcache

I've added client cache in web.config. But it is not working.

```
 <staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Fri, 03 Jan 2020 12:00:00 GMT"/>
 </staticContent>
```

Response Headers    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

I'm tesing in localhost.

Should I change anything?

Comment: The response is correct. The cache would expires on Fri, 03 Jan 2020 at 12.00 GMT. Only after that, you would see 200 response.

Comment: 304 means Cached one or it is loading from server.